# Setting JButton Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, jcomponent

I want a `JButton` to have an icon on it. So far I have this.

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Button.png");
width = ii.getIconWidth();
height = ii.getIconHeight();
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
windowW = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
windowH = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
play = new JButton("Play");
play.setSize(width, height);
play.setLocation(windowW / 2 - 165,windowH / 2 - 165);
play.setIcon(ii);
play.addActionListener(this);
```

It get the icon's width and height and then set the `JButton` to the icon's width and height but for some reason the icon will be a little to the left so that you still can see some of the `JButton`'s default texture. This is an image of how it looks like:

[image: example output]

How would I make it so that the image covers the whole `JButton` like it's supposed to?

Comment: please Icon will be resizable with JButton???,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you add  `Play` text to the button like that `new JButton("Play");`

if you delete `Play` you will see

> image covers the whole JButton